# Self referencing foreign key - mysql not set to null

Tags: mysql

Indexes :

```
Keyname    Type   Unique  Packed  Column     Cardinality Collation  Null        
parent_id  BTREE  No      No      parent_id  1           A          YES
```

Table : (comments)

```
Column      Type        Null    Default Extra
id          int(11)     No      None    AUTO_INCREMENT      
parent_id   int(11)     Yes     NULL
```

Relation view:

```
Column     Foreign key constraint (INNODB)
parent_id  'test_site'.'comments'.'id'  ON DELETE CASCADE   ON UPDATE  NO ACTION
```

Is it possible to have parent_id not set to NULL. I have tried setting the default value to '0' and inserting the value '0' but I get the following error.

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update 
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_site`.`comments`, 
CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `comments` 
(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: It's because it needs to reference an really ID, or just null. As you've set up relationships within the database by the looks of it.

Comment: If I inserted a default row and used that as a reference ID, would that work?

Comment: Probably, but why not just get rid of the constraints on your database and make sure your application covers the logic instead?

Comment: Could do, I was just wondering if it was possible, I will let the application do the work. Thank you.

Comment: @David Maybe because it's far too easy to ignore or overlook implementing constraints at the application layer, and effectively removes the constraint from being part of the model of the data.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, what is the insert statement that's failing? This looks quite similar to an exercise I set my certification class a few years ago.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to cascade a delete but not an update? It would make sense to me that if somehow the id of a 'comment' was changed, you would want it's replies or other comments to travel with it. In which case I would just cascade on update as well as delete, if you wanted to keep the constraint in there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, although you have to circumvent the foreign key constraint just once to insert a dummy record for the default value. Here's my workflow:

Here's the table creation:

```
root@localhost:playground > create table comments(id int auto_increment primary key, parent_id int not null default 0, constraint fk_parent_id foreign key (parent_id) references comments(id) on delete cascade on update cascade)engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

root@localhost:playground > show create table comments\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: comments
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `comments` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now circumvent foreign key and insert dummy record.

```
root@localhost:playground > set session foreign_key_checks=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > insert into comments (id) values (null);                                                                                              Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > set session foreign_key_checks=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > select * from comments;
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         0 |
+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > update comments set id = 0 where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

root@localhost:playground > select * from comments;
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  0 |         0 |
+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To make things neat and tidy I reset auto_increment (this is not necessary):

```
root@localhost:playground > alter table comments auto_increment=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And from now on your foreign key constraint is working properly and your column is no longer nullable and has a default value:

```
root@localhost:playground > insert into comments (id) values (null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > select * from comments;
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  0 |         0 |
|  1 |         0 |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```